# how to avoid elasticsearch process being swapped on Windows servers?

Tags: elasticsearch

From elasticsearch's website(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/referenc…), it recommends to disable memory swapping for better performance . But the approaches are for Linux only. We are planning to run the elasticsearch on Windows servers. Can we simply disable the page file on Windows? Any tips how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch team is working (as of 2015-04-06) on implementing VirtualLock on Windows:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9714#issuecomment-90182019
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/9186